# Сортировка слов по алфавиту не понимает украинские буквы

Tags: java, сортировка

Есть список слов в словаре, его надо отсортировать, и как бы все работает, но буквы є, і, ґ выходят в самом конце. Можно ли это как-то исправить или Java не любит конфеты Рошен? :с

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` и `Collections.sort()` имеют варианты принимающие вторым аргументом `Comparator<? super T>`. Надо передать предикат, который учтет правильный порядок букв.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте класс `Collator` с указанием нужной локали для сортировки:

```java
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("uk", "UA"));
Stream.of("є", "б", "ґ", "я", "і").sorted(collator).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Результат:

```
бґєія
```